# How to find if a file is fragmented or not?

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a piece of code in c#.
I am looking for a way to find if a particular file on a volume is fragmented or not.
i am not concerned with finding number of fragments of the file, but just only whether it is fragmented or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This blog post has a c# implimentation of the Defrag API for Windows:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jeffrey_wall/archive/2004/09/13/229137.aspx

It might be a good starting point.

Comment: Not only a good starting point.It already solved my problem.

I am using this function in the code:

 static public Array GetFileMap(string path)
 
 This function returns the array which contains two elements  for each fragment (most probably those are starting and ending address for each fragment. I haven't looked at the code thoroughly)
 so total length of array is exactly twice the number of fragments.
 just tried and tested now! working great!
 
 Thanks a lot